# flutter_callkit_incoming: How to navigate call screen when user accept call while app in terminate state

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebasemessaging

I have implemented Firebase Messaging for my flutter app that can sent call notification. Whenever call notification received, this packages [flutter_callkit_incoming](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming) will display call notification that allow user to accept/reject the call. When user accept the call, the app will redirect user to call screen.

Everything works perfectly but when the app in terminated state, it only open the app and will not redirect user to call screen.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

PS: I'm quite new using this stack overflow

Soo here is my relevant code to handle call notification (let me know if code is insufficient):

create a function called displayIncomingCall, config some params for it, and use packages to show incoming call notification

`await FlutterCallkitIncoming.showCallkitIncoming(params);`

added a function to identify notification type

```
enum NotiActionType { incoming_calls, others }

NotiActionType? getNotiActionType(Map<String, dynamic>? data) {
  if (data == null || data["action"] == null) return null;
  switch (data["action"]) {
    case "incoming_call":
      return NotiActionType.incoming_calls;
    default:
      return NotiActionType.others;
  }
}
```

under firebase class, create function to call displayIncomingCall

```
static Future<void> handleIncomingCallNoti(RemoteMessage? message) async {
    if (message == null) return;

    var isInsertCallLog = await Notification.insertDatabase(
      title: message.notification!.title!,
      message: message.notification!.body!,
      data: message.data,
      receiveDatetime: DateTime.now(),
    );

    if (isInsertCallLog) {
      var latestNoti = await Notification.getLatestNotification(
        dataColumnKey: Notification.actionKey,
        dataColumnValue: Notification.actionValueIncomingCall,
      );

      var props = await CallNotificationProps.fromDatabase(latestNoti);
      await CallNotification.displayIncomingCall(props);

      //set to true to alert notificationScreen fetch new data
      GlobalValue().setIsNewNotification(true);
    }
  }
```

create a function to be used inside FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {

  if (message.notification != null) {
    var apiActionType = getNotiActionType(message.data);
    if (apiActionType == NotiActionType.incoming_calls) {
      await FirebaseApi.handleIncomingCallNoti(message);
    } else {
      await Notification.insertDatabase(
        title: message.notification!.title!,
        message: message.notification!.body!,
        data: message.data,
        receiveDatetime: DateTime.now(),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

initialize an event listener for callkit packages and call it when app start

```
FlutterCallkitIncoming.onEvent.listen((CallEvent? callEvent) async {
      
      var callNoti = CallNotification(
      callNotification: CallNotificationProps.getEmptyProps,
      deviceToken: "",
    );

      switch (callEvent?.event) {
        case Event.actionCallIncoming:
          var latestNoti = await noti.Notification.getLatestNotification(
            dataColumnKey: noti.Notification.actionKey,
            dataColumnValue: noti.Notification.actionValueIncomingCall,
          );

          var actionType = getNotiActionType(latestNoti?.data);

          if (actionType == NotiActionType.incoming_calls) {
            callNoti.callNotification =
                await CallNotificationProps.fromDatabase(latestNoti);
          }
          break;
        case Event.actionCallAccept:
          
          await Navigator.pushNamed(
              context, callScreenRoute,
              arguments: {
                "call_props": callNoti,
              });
          break;
      }
    });
```

Comment: i haven't found the solution